# How to check for a specific number of integers in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a program where i require the user to enter coordinates as a string. In order to make input easier to read and make inputs like (x,y) and x , y equal I first change all non numeric characters to " " then i try and use the .matches function to check for exactly two occurrences of integers

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]"," ");
Scanner lineRead = new Scanner(input);
System.out.println(input);

if(! (input.matches( "[//d] {2}" ) )
{
bad input
}

else
{
xPosition = lineRead.nextInt();
yPosition = lineRead.nextInt();
}
```

but no matter what I input the expression returns false. Im new to using regex is my syntax wrong or is this just not something I can do?

Comment: You need something like `\d \d` Eh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than test the input against a regex, I believe the preferred way to use `Scanner` is to read the two ints you want, and catch certain exceptions if scanning does not succeed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

e.g.

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]"," ");
Scanner lineRead = new Scanner(input);
System.out.println(input);

try {
  xPosition = lineRead.nextInt();
  yPosition = lineRead.nextInt();
} catch ( 
    InputMismatchException |
    NoSuchElementException |
    IllegalStateException ex) {
  bad input
}
```

If you do want a regex that tests the input for the presence of at least two integers, I think the following would do:

```
\d+.*\b\d+
```

That's, one or more digits (`\d+`), followed by anything (`.*`), followed by a word boundary (`\b`), followed by another one-or-more-digits (`\d+`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\s*\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s*` instead of `[//d] {2}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a regex and just "searching" for the first and the second number. You start when you hit a number between 0 and 9 and stop, when you hit a non-digit. Repeat the same for the second number and you are good to go!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = scanner.nextLine();

/* Search the first number */
int i = 0;
while (i < string.length() && !Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) i++;
int j = i;
while (j < string.length() && Character.isDigit(string.charAt(j))) j++;
int firstCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i, j));

/* Search the second number */
i = j + 1;
while (i < string.length() && !Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) i++;
j = i;
while (j < string.length() && Character.isDigit(string.charAt(j))) j++;
int secondCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i, j));
```